# CRM combine columnset

Tags: .net, dynamics-crm

I have two [columnset](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb928432.aspx) object, how can I join their columns together into one object of type ColumnSet?

```
Dim col1 as new ColumnSet()
col1.AddColumn("column1")
col1.AddColumn("column2")

Dim col2 as new ColumnSet()
col2.AddColumn("column3")
col2.AddColumn("column4")
```

Crm4.0
.NET

Answer (score 0):

**CRM 4.0**

Add attributes from 'col2' to 'col1'

`col1.Attributes.AddRange(col2.Attributes);`

**CRM 2011**

To add columns from `col2` to `col1`:

`col1.Columns.AddRange(col2.Columns);`

To create new collection:

`allColumns = col1.Columns.Union(col2.Columns);`

Comment: "Columns" is not exposed in the ColumnSet class

Comment: Just realised it's 4.0. In old SDK thee is Attributes property exposed. Updated my answer

Answer (score 0):

C# Version:

```cs
ColumnSet column1 = new ColumnSet("name", "description");
ColumnSet column2 = new ColumnSet("name", "createdon");
ColumnSet merged = new ColumnSet((column1.Columns.Union(column2.Columns)).ToArray());
```

VB.NET version:

```
Dim column1 As New ColumnSet("name", "description")
Dim column2 As New ColumnSet("name", "createdon")
Dim merged As New ColumnSet((column1.Columns.Union(column2.Columns)).ToArray())
```

Union will take care of duplicated fields